# How to prevent " Confirm your email to complete sign in" page in email link - Firebaseui?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase authentication in my web app, on of my sign-in methods is email link sign-in (paswordless). While I testing I got a screen (was only able to replicate this once) which is says "Confirm Email", its located inside the header and displayed when before completing sign-in.

Is there any thing to avoid that? or what is the reason of it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you open the link on a different device or a different browser. If the user opens it on the same browser/device, they won't see this message.

It is needed for security reasons to prevent [session fixation attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation). For example I could generate the sign-in link for a popular app but trick another unsuspecting user to open that link. If the email is not confirmed, then the victim will be signed in to my account and I will be able to monitor their activity. However, if the user is asked to confirm their email, then they will be able to thwart that attack.